# Can Dictionary accept duplicate keys?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a Dictionary, and I want to search in this Dictionary by value, not by keys :-). I want to do it this way because Dictionary in JS doesn't have duplicate keys. I need to allow my program to have duplicate keys, but never duplicate values.

Example:

```
lp=new Dictionary.<int,int>();
lp.Add(2,5);
lp.Add(5,0);
lp.Add(1,3);
lp.Add(2,6);// duplicate key and error
```

After I switch value and key:

```
lp=new Dictionary.<int,int>();
lp.Add(5,2);
lp.Add(0,5);
lp.Add(3,1);
lp.Add(6,2);
```

Now I want to find keys by value because I have values in this result.

So can Dictionary accept duplicate keys in Javascript?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with JavaScript.

Comment: When you tagged this "unity", do you mean "unityscript"? (as in the script language used by the unity3d engine)

Comment: javascript for code in Unity Engine

Comment: http://www.cshandler.com/2013/01/lookup-dictionary-with-duplicate-key.html i found this but i Think  order of this code is not like normal search in dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a dictionary of lists?:

```
#pragma strict
import System.Collections.Generic;
var map = new Dictionary.<int,List.<int> >();

function Start () {
    Add(2,1);
    Add(2,2);
    Add(2,3);
    Add(3,0);
    for(var kvp in map){
        for(var v in kvp.Value){
            Debug.Log("Key: "+kvp.Key + "Value: " +v);
        }
    }
}

function Add(key:int,value:int){
    if (!map.ContainsKey(key) ){
        map[key] = new List.<int>();
    }
    map[key].Add(value);
}
```

**Update:**

Slight modification to avoid duplicate values:

```
var map = new Dictionary.<int,HashSet.<int> >();
function Add(key:int,value:int){
    if (!map.ContainsKey(key) ){
        map[key] = new HashSet.<int>();
    }
    if (map[key].Contains(value))return;
    map[key].Add(value);
}
```

These are just wrappers for C# collections so sorting a dictionary is simply:

```
function SortedKeys(){
    var keys = new List.<int>(map.Keys);
    keys.Sort();
    return keys;
}
```

List [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) is O(nlgn) average case.

Comment: thanK U really, and how can i sort this dictionary by keys?  not  O(n^2)